# Unable to bind ASP.NET 5 / Core 1.0 project with SonarLint

Tags: sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

When using SonarLint for Visual Studio 2.1, the "Bind" option is disabled when there is only an ASP.NET 5 / Core 1.0 project (.xproj) in the solution.

Is this project type supported? If it is not yet supported, when will it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project type is not supported. See also [this](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-167) Jira item to get an impression of the development and timeline.